# Inconsistent symbology presentation in QGIS 3.16.8 (between data view and outputted PDF from layout view)

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have created a polygon and applied symbology settings to it in QGIS 3.16.8 (Join style: Miter, Cap style: Square).

[image]

When I created a layout and exported to a PDF (Layout > Export to PDF) in layout view, it was found that the polygon outline symbol presentation in output PDF is different from what I created in data view. It is obvious that the angles of the polygon in data view is sharper than those in output PDF.

[image]

[image]

Are there any properties settings to avoid this problem in QGIS 3.16.8?

Comment: Change the cap style of the lines.

Comment: changed the cap style but not working